# Tint2 not showing all windows since 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, tint2

After the recent update to Ubuntu 17.10 and the switch to Gnome, Tint2 still runs but does not show all windows. Specifically, terminal windows do not appear (bot not limited to terminal).

Here is a screenshot, where my current Firefox window is visible but not my terminal.

[image]

I've been through all settings of Tint2 without finding any suitable change. The same behavior happens on another computer. If I run a session with Unity instead of Gnome, tint2 works as expected (all windows appear).

Is this a standard behavior ? Is there any known fix ?

Comment: I opened an issue for it https://gitlab.com/o9000/tint2/issues/679 but it might actually be a gnome bug. I'm a bit busy these days so it might take a while until I can look into it...

Comment: Sorry, there is no fix. Gnome is running on top of wayland now, with which tint2 is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, and I went along with it since I couldn't find any solution. I know it has nothing to do but I downloaded TeamViewer and I was having some issues, and it said something about some sessions, and I had to change these settings: in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` set `WaylandEnable=False`

I don't know what does this have to do with it, but it fixed it. Now I can see every window.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and above since then, which does not use Wayland, and the problem does not occur anymore. So fixed, in a kind of way.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 22.04LTS, and I had the same problem, and it solved.